# CompletionStage chaining when 2nd stage is not interested in the 1st stage result value

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

**Scenario**:

- there are two stages
- 2nd stage is to be executed only after the 1st one is completed
- 2nd stage is not interested in the 1st stage result but merely in the fact that the first stage is completed

Consider the existing method:

```
public <U> CompletionStage<U> thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn);
```

It doesn't quite satisfy my needs cause the function is aware of the 1st stage result value `? super T`

What I would rather like to have is something like:

```
public <U> CompletionStage<U> thenApply(Supplier<? extends U> fn);
```

**Question**: do I understand correctly that there's no out-of-the-box solution for that so I will have to write my own wrapper function in order to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Why does this bother you so much? Just use a parameter name like `__` to keep it short.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: well if you already have a `Supplier`, you have to do, `__->supplier.get()`

Comment: Why is the code of a `Supplier` required to wait for the completion of another, completely unrelated action? That smells like a really bad design, i.e. hidden side effect dependencies.

Comment: @Holger behind is a complicated system with eventual consistency. I have 3 stages that are to be executed in order but if 1st or 3rd fail then it's not a critical situation and I still want to run the 2nd stage.

Comment: Well, you didn’t disprove the assumed design smell. You just told what was already known. You have stages “that are to be executed in order”, despite the fact that they appear to be unrelated.

Comment: @Holger, I agree with the assertion of a design smell; but doesn't the same smell affect `thenRun()`, which _is_ part of the API? Would `thenSupply()` be any worse?

Comment: @jaco0646 you’re right, even the builtin `thenRun` should be used with care. There are legitimate use cases, e.g. when you use `CompletableFuture.allOf(…)`, it doesn’t provide a useful result but requires you to query the input futures for their results in the dependent stage. Still, occurrences of dependent functions, not using the result the are specified to depend on, raise suspicions and in this specific case, they were correct. A `thenSupply` would not be different, but it could create confusion with the `static` `supplyAsync` methods or the newer `completeAsync​(Supplier [, Executor])`…

Answer (score 2):

There is no such built-in solution. But you could "abuse" [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [`thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Supplier<String> sup = ()->"s";
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->4)
        .thenCompose(x->CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sup))
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

BTW, I guess probably there are no such convenience methods because CompletionStage/CompletableFuture already have quite many methods.

Comment: What’s the advantage of `.thenCompose(x->CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sup))` over `.thenApply( x -> sup.get() )`?

Comment: @Holger: well admittedly, there is no real advantage, and there is even the limitation that an `xxxAsync()` method has to be used. But `Supplier.get()` has not to be called explicitly. Somehow it feels more "abstract" if `get()` has not to be called explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you want to run is not expected to return a result, you can use `thenRun`:

```
CompletableFuture<Thing> thingsFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getThings());
thingsFuture.thenRun(() -> System.out.println("Got ALL THE THINGS!"));
```

If you need it to return a result, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.  Best option you have is just to ignore the argument in your lambda.